# Update column where column like other column

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains Country names and ISO codes lets name it country, the other table has call destination names, lets call it prefix. I added a column named 'iso' in prefix table to save ISO codes. I need to update prefix.iso where prefix.destination like country.names

Country names are complete country names
Country destination has the name of the country and the name of the local provider or city
example: United States T-mobile, or Australia Orange

I am trying a query like this but it's not doing the job

```
UPDATE `prefix`, `country` SET `prefix`.`iso` =  `country`.`countrycode` WHERE `prefix`.`destination` LIKE CONCAT(`country`.`countrycode`,'%')
```

Comment: How is your query not working?

Comment: I you put an example dataset(just 2 rows at least) of both tables and an example of the desired result, we can help you a lot

Comment: after I run it I get that 0 rows affected.

Comment: Here is the structure of the tables<br>
SELECT `id`, `countrycode`, `countryprefix`, `countryname` FROM `country`<br>
SELECT `prefix`, `destination`, `iso` FROM `prefix`

Comment: what does return "SELECT count(*) FROM `prefix`, `country` WHERE `prefix`.`destination` LIKE CONCAT(`country`.`countrycode`,'%');" ?

Comment: When I run the query I get 0

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine. Ensure that your values in the country table are as expected.

```
mysql> USE test;
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE country (id SERIAL, countrycode VARCHAR(2));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE prefix (destination VARCHAR(8), iso VARCHAR(2));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO country VALUES (1, "CA"), (2, "US");
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO prefix VALUES ("Canada", ""), ("USA", "");
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> UPDATE prefix, country SET iso = countrycode WHERE destination LIKE CONCAT(countrycode,'%');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM prefix;
+-------------+------+
| destination | iso  |
+-------------+------+
| Canada      | CA   |
| USA         | US   |
+-------------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```